# Implementing SOLID Principles with C# Asp.net

Tags: c#, design-patterns, asp.net

I have started learning about SOLID principles yesterday. I've got a detailed explanation of SOLID principles [here](http://cre8ivethought.com/blog/2011/08/23/software-development-is-not-a-jenga-game). After reading it, and a few other articles, I have tried to apply these principles in one of my projects.

This is a tool for importing data from another system. Requirements are as follows:

1. Read some settings from SQL Server database.
2. Call an external system API with read settings.
3. API returns the result in Json format.
4. Returned results should be saved in SQL Server Database.

**Following code sample is in C# with Asp.Net**

I have a form that initiates the import process on a button's click event.

```
private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            IReader _reader = new DBReader();
            Interfaces.IWriter _writer = new Classes.DBWriter();
            
            Interfaces.IExternalSystemInteraction _externalSystem = new Classes.JSonExternalSystem(_writer);

            Classes.Client _client = new PxImportApplication.Classes.Client(_reader, _externalSystem);
            _client.Invoke();
        }
```

- `DBReader` class inherits from `IReader` interface and does the job to read settings from SQL server database. We can create a new class if there is a requirement to read from MySQL database instead of SQLServer.
- Similary `DBWriter` writes into SQL Server database and implements IWriter interface.
- `JSonExternalSystem` class hits the API and reads data into Json format. IWriter interface instance is passed to get the Json data so that it could write that data into the SQL Server DB.

Client class has the following implementation:

```
class Client
    {
        private IReader _reader;
        private Interfaces.IExternalSystemInteraction _externalSystemInformation;

        public Client(IReader reader, Interfaces.IExternalSystemInteraction externalSystem)
        {
            _reader = reader;
            _externalSystemInformation = externalSystem;
            
        }

    public void Invoke()
        {
            List<IProperties> lstProperties = _reader.ReadData();
            _externalSystemInformation.HitAPI(lstProperties);
        }
    }
```

JSONExternalSystem's implementation is as follows:

```
class JSonExternalSystem : Interfaces.IExternalSystemInteraction
    {
     
        private Interfaces.IWriter _writer;

        public JSonExternalSystem(Interfaces.IWriter writer)
        {
            _writer = writer;
        }

        #region IExternalSystemInteraction Members

        public void HitAPI(List<IProperties> properties)
        {
           foreach (IProperties property in properties)
            {
                ReadJsonFormat(property.Xproperty);
                _writer.ImportToDataBase();
          
            }
        }    
   }
```

My question is: By looking at this much code, do you think that I am on the right way to implement SOLID principles? I know that this doesn't show the whole implementation but most of the code for other classes goes more or less like the above given classes. I am sure I must be lacking somewhere as this is just my second day. Kindly correct me.

Answer (score 5):

When you say *I have a form that initiates import process on a button's click event*, you've coupled your UI with some "business logic". Let's look at that `Click` handler:

> ```
> private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
>    {
>        IReader _reader = new DBReader();
>        Interfaces.IWriter _writer = new Classes.DBWriter();
>
>        Interfaces.IExternalSystemInteraction _externalSystem = new Classes.JSonExternalSystem(_writer);
>
>        Classes.Client _client = new PxImportApplication.Classes.Client(_reader, _externalSystem);
>        _client.Invoke();
>    }
> ```

**Naming**

This method handles the click of a button, I'd infer a button named `btnStart` and say that the naming convention you're using for control names is breaking the naming convention for method names - how about naming the button `StartButton` and handle the `Click` event in a `StartButton_Click`, or `OnStartButtonClick` method? In my opinion the reasons why *btnStart* is a bad name would be something like:

- *Hungarian Notation* is used, "btn" being a short for `Button`, which is a type.
- *Disemvoweling* turned "button" into "btn".
- *camelCase* breaks the *PascalCase* convention for naming methods, because the convention for event handlers is `void [objectName]_[eventName](object sender, EventArgs e)`.

**Type qualification**

If, at the top of your code file, you added the following:

```
using PxImportApplication.Classes;
using PxImportApplication.Interfaces;
```

Your handler code could read like this:

```
private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       var reader = new DBReader();
       var writer = new DBWriter();

       var externalSystem = new JSonExternalSystem(writer);

       var client = new Client(reader, externalSystem);
       client.Invoke();
   }
```

Fully-qualified types make the code harder to read. I noticed you used `_` in front of local variables; I prefer to use the underscore for private fields, if at all.

**Dependencies**

The problem with this approach, is that by instantiating that form you automatically get a `new DBReader` and a `new DBWriter`, with absolutely no way of swapping these two with a mock implementation - actually you don't really have another way of testing this piece of logic, other than <kbd>F5</kbd> and run the thing and click the button and see how it goes.

In fact, the UI is *tightly coupled* with the `DBReader`, `DBWriter` (which should be `DbReader` and `DbWriter`), `Client` and `JSonExternalSystem`. Whenever you `new` up something, you've identified a *dependency*. Most classes of the .net framework are ok to instantiate on the fly like this, other dependencies should be clearly stated, in the form's constructor. Keep the parameterless default constructor so that you won't break the designer, but make another that takes all other dependencies. Too many (4? 5? 6? Your call!) constructor parameters (/dependencies) is a sign that your class is starting to break the *Single Responsibility Principle*.

I think the form is doing much more than just *being a UI* here, and the dependencies really are, is dependencies of another type, namely `PxImportApplication.Classes.Client`.

What the button really needs to do, is instantiate a `Client` and call the `Invoke()` method (a confusing name that breaks POLS, `Invoke` is .net lingo for synchroneously calling a delegate). All this `new`ing up is covering-up the real intent. How about having a click handler doing this:

```
private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       var client = _clientFactory.Create();
       client.Invoke(); // todo: rename this method
}
```

This code means the handler now only *depends* on a `_clientFactory` private field:

```
private readonly IFactory _clientFactory;
```

And this field can be instantiated from the form's parameterized constructor:

```
public Form1(IFactory clientFactory) : this()
{
    _clientFactory = clientFactory;
}
```

The factory class has its own dependencies:

```
private readonly IReader _reader;
private readonly IExternalSystemInteraction _externalSystem;

public ClientFactory(IReader reader, IExternalSystemInteraction externalSystem)
{
    _reader = reader;
    _externalSystem = externalSystem;
}

public IClient Create()
{
    return new Client(_reader, _externalSystem);
}
```

The `ClientFactory` class *implements* the `IFactory` interface, which simply exposes a parameterless `Create()` method - and that's everything the form needs to know.

---

Your constructor-injected private fields can be made `readonly` in both `Client` and `JSonExternalSystem` classes (should be `JsonExternalSystem`). You're doing it right in these classes - don't do DI halfway though, do it all the way. Creating instances of types is the role of factory/infrastructure classes and of the application's *composition root*. If you're using an IoC container you don't have to resolve the dependencies yourself. This means if the `IReader` that the factory class takes has dependencies of its own, you don't need to bother with them; by *letting go* of the control you have over the types that a type can instantiate, your code becomes very focused, *cohesive*. *High cohesion, low coupling* is what you want to achieve.

Comment: Ooh, I should have double-checked the tags before answering. I took "form" as in `System.Windows.Forms`... DI is a bit different in this case (because the *page* is your *composition root*), I'll edit my post accordingly when I have a chance, but most of it still stands. Just don't bother with "the form's constructor" :)

Comment: I read the points you mentioned carefully. Your point about high cohesion and low coupling is very true. I have two questions here: 1) As a programmer, how can I reduce the chances of breaking SRP, as you said above, "Too many (4? 5? 6? Your call!) constructor parameters (/dependencies) is a sign that your class is starting to break the Single Responsibility Principle." 2) At some point of time I will need to initialize  IReader reader = new DbReader();, somewhere. What should be that point ? For eg; In a windows application should I initialize it in Main() method of program.cs ?

Comment: Regarding 1, many times multiple dependencies are related and can be regrouped into one; 2, that should be as close as possible to your *composition root*.. but in asp.net that entry point isn't exactly as clear-cut as a `Main()` method would be.

Comment: So I guess idea is to keep those points to minimum where we need to initialize objects of a particular type. Right ?